# Split slide into limited list ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ngfor

i have 12 or more in item, i need split show 3 heading in one slide, next 3 heading in next slide

```
<ion-slides pager *ngFor="let item of list" let-i="index">
  <ion-slide>
    <h2>{{item.text}}</h2>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

Comment: What have you tried already? It looks like you are iterating on a wrong item - if you want to have multiple h2-s in a single ion-slide.

Comment: add  *ngIf="i<3" but this show first 3 only

Answer (score 0):

**your component**

```
private page = 0, pageSize = 3;
private list = []; // your array goes here

getItems() {
    let index = this.page * this.pageSize;
    return this.list.slice(index, index + this.pageSize);
}
```

**your html**

```
<ion-slides pager *ngFor="let item of getItems()">
   <ion-slide>
    <h2>{{item.text}}</h2>
   </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

You just need to set update your `page` according to the items you want to see.

Comment: I would suggesst using something like left and right arrows to decrement or increment it.

Comment: i get 3 slides one by one order